# SwiftUI - Animating count text from 0 to x

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to animate a text that starts by default from 0, to a variable.

For example, for x = 80, I want my text to display all the numbers between 0 and 80 very fast, until it hits 80.
I found examples with progress indicators, but I cannot apply the methods to this.

Do you have any ideas for doing this?

Thanks, Diocrasis.

Answer (score 4):

Here I've created a little function called `runCounter` which takes a binding to the `counter` variable, a `start` value, the `end` value, and the `speed`.  When called, it sets the bound variable to the `start` value, and then starts a `Timer` which runs every `speed` seconds and increments the counter until it reaches `end` at which point it invalidates the `timer`.

This standalone example shows two counters running at different speeds, both of which start when they first appear using `.onAppear()`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var counter1 = 0
    @State private var counter2 = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
        Text("\(self.counter1)")
            .onAppear {
                self.runCounter(counter: self.$counter1, start: 0, end: 80, speed: 0.05)
            }
        Text("\(self.counter2)")
            .onAppear {
                self.runCounter(counter: self.$counter2, start: 0, end: 10, speed: 0.5)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func runCounter(counter: Binding<Int>, start: Int, end: Int, speed: Double) {
        counter.wrappedValue = start

        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: speed, repeats: true) { timer in
            counter.wrappedValue += 1
            if counter.wrappedValue == end {
                timer.invalidate()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a significant improvement, but even setting the speed to 0.0001 is still too slow when counting large numbers.

Comment: I am using this in a project.  I posted tweaked code below where I set the maximum number of steps required to get from 0 to the end number.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that leverages SwiftUI's built-in animation capabilities. As a result, it doesn't need to manage any timers or animation loops itself.

It's not limited to moving from `0` to a final number, either. Any change in the `value` performed in a `withAnimation` block will animate the change in value by moving through intermediate values.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct AnimatedNumberTextView<Content>: View, Animatable where Content: View {
    private var value: Double
    @ViewBuilder private let content: (Int) -> Content
    
    init(_ value: Int, content: @escaping (Int) -> Content) {
        self.value = Double(value)
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var animatableData: Double {
        get { value }
        set { value = newValue }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        content(Int(value))
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var number = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Riches:")

            AnimatedNumberTextView(number) { value in
                Text("\(value) ")
                    .monospaced()
            }.frame(minWidth: 140, alignment: .trailing)
        }
        .padding(.bottom)
        .onAppear {
            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 2)) {
                number = 87654321
            }
        }
        
        Button("Randomise!") {
            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1)) {
                number = Int.random(in: 0...87654321)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Inspired by [this blog](https://stefanblos.com/posts/animating-number-changes/) and [this blog](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/06/17/the-magic-of-animatable-values-in-swiftui/).)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Timer.Publisher` to trigger incrementing of your counter at regular intervals.

To stop incrementing once you reach your desired count, whenever your `Timer` fires, you can check if `count` has reached `end`, if not, increment it, otherwise remove the subscription and hence stop incrementing.

```
class Counter: ObservableObject {
    @Published var count = 0
    let end: Int

    private var timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init(end: Int) {
        self.end = end
    }

    func start() {
        timer.sink { [weak self] _ in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            if self.count <=self.end {
                self.count += 1
            } else {
                self.subscriptions.removeAll()
            }
        }.store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
}

struct AnimatedText: View {
    @ObservedObject var counter: Counter

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(counter.count)")
            .onAppear() {
                self.counter.start()
            }
    }
}


struct AnimatedText_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AnimatedText(counter: Counter(end: 80))
    }
}
```

Comment: your code is finishing on 81 and not on 80, and 0.5 seconds between updates is really not considered 'very fast', i changed it to 0.1 and it is still too slow for a counter something like this: https://static.schoolofmotion.com/f52be17e-b040-46b7-b835-672d9b3da47b/Money_Counter.gif

Comment: In case you're wondering to use AnimatedText inside another View, the counter variable in AnimatedText should be defined as `@StateObject` and not ObservedObject. This fixed my issue because of how StateObjects are able to redraw only part of a view

Comment: @Shaybc you can update the timer to publish every 0.001 seconds or something like that to your liking if you want it to count up faster. Also update the if condition inside `start` function to be if self.count < self.end and that should fix the problem 80 vs 81 as well. And please see my comment above for embedding this inside another View so that it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer by @vacawama.

```
func runCounter(counter: Binding<Int>, start: Int, end: Int, speed: Double) {
    let maxSteps = 20
    counter.wrappedValue = start
    
    let steps = min(abs(end), maxSteps)
    var increment = 1
    if steps == maxSteps {increment = end/maxSteps}

    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: speed, repeats: true) { timer in
        counter.wrappedValue += increment
        if counter.wrappedValue >= end {
            counter.wrappedValue = end
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this simple solution with a timer:

```
extension Timer {
    static func scheduledProgressTimer(duration: TimeInterval, block: @escaping ((_ progress: Double) -> Void), completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        let startDate = Date()
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0 / 60, repeats: true) { timer in
            let interval = Date().timeIntervalSince(startDate)
            let progress = min(1.0, abs(interval / duration))
            block(progress)
            if progress >= 1.0 {
                timer.invalidate()
                completion?()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State var counter: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Counter: \(counter)")
            Button("Start counting") {
                let endValue = 80
                Timer.scheduledProgressTimer(duration: 2) { progress in
                    counter = Int(progress * Double(endValue))
                } completion: {
                    print("Finished!")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```